# Struggling to make SMCC

Tags: synthesis

I have attempted to synthesize SMCC (succinimidyl 4-(N-maleimidomethyl)cyclohexane-1-carboxylate) following the lit protocol in [*J. Org. Chem.* **2011,** *76*, *21*, 9169–9174](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo201686e). Except for the scale, I followed the protocol exactly and the purity of starting materials is confirmed with NMR analysis.
[image: Overall Scheme]
For the raw product, I recorded a $\ce{^1H}$-NMR spectrum.  Since this analysis was not conclusive, the sample was characterized by  ESI-MS spectrum before moving on to the purification step (trituration with diethyl ether). However, what I saw on the ESI Ms was 353.24 (relative abundance 100%), 375.18 (65%), 705.04 (40%), and 726.99 (70%). I am concerned with the complete absence of the desired mass peak (Exact Mass: 334.12, and no M+1 or M+23 peaks were found), and unable to figure out a potential side-reaction that gave the mass peak at 353.24.

Comment: Too few information. Since the publication describes multiple esters, it would be beneficial if you summarize your synthesis in a brief reaction scheme which includes a structure formula of your starting reagent and intended product. Contrary to IR and NMR, the shape of MS spectra very much depends on the experimental conditions to record the spectrum. Did you monitor advancement of the reaction, e.g., by TLC (e.g. by cross-spotting starting material(s) and reaction)? What if you have your product in one of the washing solutions from (back) extraction you likely still have under the fume hood?

Comment: @Buttonwood Ok, will do now. I should have outlined it better. I was making the compound 3i following the Representative Procedure B from pg 9172-9173.

Comment: Also would be good to know conditions for ESI. I would assume 353 peak is M + H2O +1.

Comment: Is there strong evidence (e.g., quenched aliquote, then MS (direct injection)) the esterification between maleic anhydride and amine proceeded well? By own experience, I'm hesitant to telescope (no isolation/workup) a new sequence right on first attempt. It won't travel well on the normal phase plate (perhaps better on neutral silica) and anyway requires a derivatisation in a stain, after elution and drying).

Comment: If you followed the protocol "exactly" and were unsuccessful, that would imply that the protocol is incorrect. Alternatively, you didn't follow the protocol "exactly" ;).

Comment: @user55119, Organic synthesis in research journals is not that reproducible because authors often fail/forget to write sufficient details. This is why only reliable protocols are those which have been reproduced in another lab e.g. the database of Organic Synthesis.

Comment: @user55119 There is a good number of publications where (even if the SI put less constrain on page numbers, than the body of publication [e.g. [Baran's 11 step Maoecrystal V approach](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jacs.6b06623)]) where experimental details are left out for whatever reason. Validation of protocols (like by Org.Syn.) is not as widespread as it could be. It is not only about «reproducible science» if lack of data shared puts additional difficulty (both about time and $$$ for chemicals/experiments) to your work when colleagues in the same group do this intentionally.

Comment: In lab classes you might be pushed to write detailed reports (depends on the TAs and on the specialty, though, analytical chemistry and physical chemistry tend to be more aware about things like standard deviation, etc. than organic chemistry).  And once the students become profs, well, other things enter the focus.

Comment: @M.Farooq,@Buttonwood. I'm well-aware of the truth of both of your comments. I was in the business for decades. Did you notice the little ;) at the end of my comment? My issue was the term exactly. ;)

Comment: @user55119, You will also agree that some synthetic chemists also hide the details to prevent their competitors from catching up. There was one famous case, where the author mentioned a wrong metals in superconductors work (?) in Nature or some other big journal. When other researcher tried to reproduce, they could not. Later he published a correction. The exact details escape, it was mentioned by a teacher in class a decade ago.

Comment: @M. Farooq: Deviousness occurring among chemists? I am as shocked as Captain Renault in Casablanca.

Comment: @user55119 I admit that the claim that 'followed the protocol exactly' can be subjective.